# how to make HTTPS request in esp8266?

Tags: rest, https, esp8266, esp32

I once wanted to get THERMOCOUPLE DATA and by making HTTP request I put it on API 
it worked flawlessly , here is the code  for esp32:

```cpp
// this example is public domain. enjoy! https://learn.adafruit.com/thermocouple/

#include "max6675.h"
#include <ArduinoJson.h>
#include <HTTPClient.h>
#include <WiFiMulti.h>

int thermoDO = 19;
int thermoCS = 23;
int thermoCLK = 5;

MAX6675 thermocouple(thermoCLK, thermoCS, thermoDO);
const char *AP_SSID = "ssid";
const char *AP_PWD = "pass";
  
WiFiMulti wifiMulti;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
   
  delay(4000);
  wifiMulti.addAP(AP_SSID, AP_PWD);
 
 

  Serial.println("MAX6675 test");
  // wait for MAX chip to stabilize
  delay(500);
}

void loop() {
  // basic readout test, just print the current temp
  
  Serial.print("C = "); 
  Serial.println(thermocouple.readCelsius());
  Serial.print("F = ");
  Serial.println(thermocouple.readFahrenheit());
  
  // For the MAX6675 to update, you must delay AT LEAST 250ms between reads!
  delay(1000);
  postDataToServer();
}

 
void postDataToServer() {
 
  Serial.println("Posting JSON data to server...");
  // Block until we are able to connect to the WiFi access point
  if (wifiMulti.run() == WL_CONNECTED) {
     
    HTTPClient http;   
     
    http.begin("https://retoolapi.dev/fyXalF/data/1");  
    http.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");         
     
    StaticJsonDocument<200> doc;
    // Add values in the document
    //
    doc["temp1"] = thermocouple.readCelsius();
    doc["temp2"] = thermocouple.readFahrenheit();
   
     
    String requestBody;
    serializeJson(doc, requestBody);
     
    int httpResponseCode = http.PUT(requestBody);
 
    if(httpResponseCode>0){
       
      String response = http.getString();                       
       
      Serial.println(httpResponseCode);   
      Serial.println(response);
     
    }
    else {
     
      Serial.printf("Error occurred while sending HTTP POST");
       
    }
     
  }
}
```

now I'm trying to do it by esp8266. 
so the code is basically the same , you have to put "ESP8266" before library names and for making http.begin() you have to pass a  WiFiClient beside API address :

```cpp
// this example is public domain. enjoy! https://learn.adafruit.com/thermocouple/

#include "max6675.h"
#include <ArduinoJson.h>
#include <ESP8266HTTPClient.h>
#include <ESP8266WiFiMulti.h>
#include <WiFiClientSecure.h>

int thermoDO = 19;
int thermoCS = 23;
int thermoCLK = 5;

MAX6675 thermocouple(thermoCLK, thermoCS, thermoDO);
const char *AP_SSID = "ssid";
const char *AP_PWD = "pass";
  
ESP8266WiFiMulti wifiMulti;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
   
  delay(4000);
  wifiMulti.addAP(AP_SSID, AP_PWD);
 
 

  Serial.println("MAX6675 test");
  // wait for MAX chip to stabilize
  delay(500);
}

void loop() {
  // basic readout test, just print the current temp
  
  Serial.print("C = "); 
  Serial.println(thermocouple.readCelsius());
  Serial.print("F = ");
  Serial.println(thermocouple.readFahrenheit());
  
  // For the MAX6675 to update, you must delay AT LEAST 250ms between reads!
  delay(1000);
  postDataToServer();
}

 
void postDataToServer() {
 
  Serial.println("Posting JSON data to server...");
  // Block until we are able to connect to the WiFi access point
  if (wifiMulti.run() == WL_CONNECTED) {
    WiFiClient client;
    HTTPClient http;   
     
    http.begin(client,"https://retoolapi.dev/fyXalF/data/1");  
    http.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");         
     
    StaticJsonDocument<200> doc;
    // Add values in the document
    //
    doc["temp1"] = thermocouple.readCelsius();
    doc["temp2"] = thermocouple.readFahrenheit();
   
     
    String requestBody;
    serializeJson(doc, requestBody);
     
    int httpResponseCode = http.PUT(requestBody);
 
    if(httpResponseCode>0){
       
      String response = http.getString();                       
       
      Serial.println(httpResponseCode);   
      Serial.println(response);
     
    }
    else {
     
      Serial.printf("Error occurred while sending HTTP POST");
       
    }
     
  }
}
```

it compiled but I got **"bad request-400"**  and "**The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port**" as a response . 
I think the esp8266 library cant send https requests ... 
any ideas how to solve this ? 
PS : I also use **#include <WiFiClientSecure.h>**

```cpp
    WiFiClientSecure client;
    HTTPClient http;   
     
    http.begin(client,"https://retoolapi.dev/0tvafA/data/1");
```

it's not working either : **Error occurred while sending HTTP POSTC = 0.00**
:(

Comment: use `WiFiClientSecure client`

Comment: it's not working

Comment: try `client.setInsecure();` before http.begin

Comment: YOU ARE A DOLL :)

Comment: Better than switching off SSL validation would be to understand how to do it properly. See the example at https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/tree/master/libraries/ESP8266WiFi/examples/HTTPSRequest. There is also an extended example at https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/blob/master/libraries/ESP8266WiFi/examples/BearSSL_Validation/BearSSL_Validation.ino that demonstrates the various validation strategies.